# Sakai 10 Building Error

Tags: maven, tomcat, sakai

I'm trying to install Sakai 10.2 and it gives me an error every time. I've reinstall everything, including de OS. And the error persist.

This is my current configuration:

- Sakai 10.2
- Maven 3.2.5
- Tomcat 7.0.59

This the error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------        ------
[INFO] Total time: 02:00 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-17T17:56:31+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 347M/829M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project entitybroker-restimpl: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\opt\sakai-10.x\entitybroker\rest\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :entitybroker-restimpl
```

These are de reports of the test.

[EntityDescriptionManagerTest](http://pastebin.com/XpkD5BdV)
[EntityHandlerImplTest](http://pastebin.com/drJWL7sh)
[EntityBrokerServlet]`http://pastebin.com/vWmbNXxa`

Comment: What version of java jdk are you using? Did you try with the latest version of Sakai 10 (10.x or 10.4)?

Comment: I'm using  Java JDK 1.7.075-b13.

Yes, im following this guide, so i'd try with both  versions.

https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=93028745

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an error in the tests.
Build Sakai with `-Dmaven.test.skip`.

Could you also file a Jira at http://jira.sakaiproject.org with the test errors and someone can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Problem solved. I don't know how and I don't know the cause of the problem.

I've update JDK to _076 version and skip the test. It have no sense for me.

But it's done.

Thank you for your time and your help.